# Pre-test tasks using pytest markers?

Tags: python, pytest

I've got a Python application using pytest. For several of my tests, there are API calls to Elasticsearch (using elasticsearch-dsl-py) that slow down my tests that I'd like to:

1. prevent unless a Pytest marker is used.
2. If a marker is used, I would want that marker to execute some code before the test runs. Just like how a fixture would work if you used `yield`.

This is mostly inspired by pytest-django where you have to use the `django_db` marker in order to make a conn to the database (but they throw an error if you try to connect to the DB, whereas I just don't want a call in the first place, that's all).

For example:

```py
def test_unintentionally_using_es():
    """I don't want a call going to Elasticsearch. But they just happen. Is there a way to "mock" the call? Or even just prevent the call from happening?"""

@pytest.mark.elastic
def test_intentionally_using_es():
    """I would like for this marker to perform some tasks beforehand (i.e. clear the indices)"""

# To replicate that second test, I currently use a fixture:
@pytest.fixture
def elastic():
    # Pre-test tasks
    yield something
```

I think that's a use-case for markers right? Mostly inspired by pytest-django.

Comment: `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("elastic")`?

Comment: For mocking elasticsearch, check out e.g. [`elasticmock`](https://pypi.org/project/ElasticMock/)

Comment: Thanks @hoefling Ah I think the `usefixtures` decorator is perfect for the second case rather than markers. But how would I prevent calls to ES by default (as in when no markers/fixture are applied)?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now, will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial approach with having a combination of a fixture and a custom marker is the correct one; in the code below, I took the code from your question and filled in the gaps.

Suppose we have some dummy function to test that uses the official [`elasticsearch`](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch) client:

```
# lib.py

from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


def f():
    es = Elasticsearch()
    es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
    return es.index(
        index="my-index",
        id=42,
        body={"any": "data", "timestamp": datetime.now()},
    )
```

We add two tests, one is not marked with `elastic` and should operate on fake client, the other one is marked and needs access to real client:

```
# test_lib.py

from lib import f


def test_fake():
    resp = f()
    assert resp["_id"] == "42"


@pytest.mark.elastic
def test_real():
    resp = f()
    assert resp["_id"] == "42"
```

Now let's write the `elastic()` fixture that will mock the `Elasticsearch` class depending on whether the `elastic` marker was set:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def elastic(request):
    should_mock = request.node.get_closest_marker("elastic") is None
    if should_mock:
        patcher = patch('lib.Elasticsearch')
        fake_es = patcher.start()
        # this is just a mock example
        fake_es.return_value.index.return_value.__getitem__.return_value = "42"
    else:
        ...  # e.g. start the real server here etc
    yield
    if should_mock:
        patcher.stop()
```

Notice the usage of `autouse=True`: the fixture will be executed on each test invocation, but only do the patching if the test is *not* marked. This presence of the marker is checked via `request.node.get_closest_marker("elastic") is None`. If you run both tests now, `test_fake` will pass because `elastic` mocks the `Elasticsearch.index()` response, while `test_real` will fail, assuming you don't have a server running on port 9200.

Comment: Super happy with this answer!!! I've never learned how to properly use mocks and patch. I think this is a good enough answer to get a foot hold, so accepted. I guess my only concern is that you were mocking a specific return case. I was hoping for a way to block the calls, but I think the Elasticsearch mock library would probably do. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yea correct me if I'm wrong -- this is more of a note to self I suppose -- but using the Elasticmock library would probably mean not using their decorator but instead patching using `_get_elasticmock`. https://github.com/vrcmarcos/elasticmock/blob/f91029fb30edf85f928ff9328058f46b8bfbbd11/elasticmock/__init__.py#L30-L33

Comment: @acw you can also just do `patcher = patch('lib.Elasticsearch', FakeElasticsearch)`; `_get_elasticmock` is just a way to cache fake clients for reusing. I agree the public API of `elasticmock` is pretty laconic though, could offer more mocking possibilities.